# Buck Converter AP62201

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

I am using the [AP62201](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP62200_AP62201_AP62200T.pdf).
Do I need to connect its EN pin anywhere? In the reference design EN pin is connected nowhere.
Kindly advise, I am new to electronics.

Comment: Did you read the datasheet description how the EN pin works?

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the datasheet:

> Drive EN high to turn on the regulator and
> low to turn it off. Leave floating for automatic startup.

So if you leave it floating the chip will be enabled. This is also shown in the block diagram by the current source pulling the EN pin up.

Comment: Thanks dear for informing. Actually I am using a button which will switch R1 for two different voltages (1V, 2.5V) as input is 14V. As you said EN internally connected to a current source and in the diagram its mentioned that after reaching 1.2V it will turn on. Can you please clear that it will turn on automatically for 1V output design if I left EN floating?

Comment: @IffiHus The EN pin/UVLO works with the input voltage, it has nothing to do with the output voltage. So yes, it should work with a 14V input if you leave EN floating.